# One-to-one correspondence between mean value and parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, statistical-inference

I am currently taking a course in statistics, and in this course we are considering linear models $\mu = X\beta$ where $\mu \in L$ and $L = col(X)$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $X$ is the design matrix and $\beta$ are the parameters. In this course, our lecturer has repeatedly emphasised that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mu$ and $\beta$ if and only if $X$ has full column rank.

However, I am simply not able to see how this can be the case. My reasoning is as follows. If there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mu$ and $\beta$, then $X$ must be bijective, i.e. be both injective and surjective. Injectivity follows quite easily from the fact that $X$ has full column rank. According to my limited knowledge of linear algebra, however, a matrix is surjective if and only if it has full row rank, which, together with injectivity means that $X$ is square, but the design matrix is certainly not square in general, in fact it almost always has more rows than columns. I have a vague idea that surjectivity may somehow follow from the fact that $L = col(X)$ and $L$ is a linear subspace, but I can't see exactly how this avoids the problem of making the design matrix square.

Where is my thinking wrong and how can I prove that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mu$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Injectivity of $X$ is enough if it comes to a one-to-one correspondence between the domain of $X$ and its *image* $L$ (so not the whole space $\mathbb R^n$). Restricting to image is somehow a way to create surjectivity. Could that be the answer?

Comment: @drhab I think you're right, but I have difficulty getting the details down, and I also still don't understand how this does not make the design matrix square. If you can elaborate a bit on this, it would probably be a good answer.

Comment: Do you agree that there is a one-to-one correspondence between space
$L=\left\{ \left(\beta,\beta\right)^{T}\mid\beta\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $
and $\mathbb{R}$? This on base of relation $\mu=\left(\beta,\beta\right)^{T}=X\beta$
where $X$ is the $2\times1$ matrix with $x_{11}=x_{21}=1$? This is an example and looking at it can help understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked into it some more, I have found an answer with the help of drhab's comments.

Injectivity follows from the fact that the columns of $X$ are linearly independent, so if $X\beta_1 = X\beta_2$, then $X(\beta_1 - \beta_2) = 0$, so $\beta_1 = \beta_2$, and $X$ is injective.

Surjectivity follows from the fact that $X$ maps to the linear subspace $L = col(X) = \{ \alpha_1 X_1 + \dots + \alpha_k X_k \; | \; (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k\}$,
and we see that $X\beta = \beta_1 X_1 + \dots + \beta_k X_k$, so all of $L$ is hit by $X$, and $X$ is therefore surjective.